# Joint Probability, Covariance, Correlation Example

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, covariance, correlation

Its my solution for this question
[image: Its my solution for this question]

$$ f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
     x^2+\frac{xy}{3}, & 0<x<1, \quad 0<y<2 \\ 
                            0, &\textrm{otherwise}\\ 
\end{cases}$$
then calculate  $\rho(X,Y)$ ?

**Note:**   $\rho$ is the Rho.   I solved this question but I find the $\rho(X,Y) = -0.051$ but my teacher says it's the wrong answer? How can I solve this problem correctly.

Comment: How did you get your answer?

Comment: i was added photo but they said remove photo. i'm adding photo right now for see my solution   *** Added the photo for solution ***

Answer (score 0):

Well, your  calculations are correct, but the final answer is not *equal to* -0.5132 .  That is only an approximation.

$\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=(x^2+xy/3)\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1}
\\[2ex]\mathsf E(X) &= \int_0^1\int_0^2 x f(x,y)~\mathrm dy~\mathrm d x
\\[1ex] &= 13/18
\\[2ex]\mathsf E(X^2) &= \int_0^1\int_0^2 x^2 f(x,y)~\mathrm dy~\mathrm d x
\\[1ex] &= 17/30
\\[2ex]\mathsf {Var}(X) &= \mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2
\\[1ex] &= 73/1620
\\[2ex]\mathsf E(Y) &= \int_0^1\int_0^2 y f(x,y)~\mathrm dy~\mathrm d x
\\[1ex] &= 10/9
\\[2ex]\mathsf E(Y^2) &= \int_0^1\int_0^2 y^2 f(x,y)~\mathrm dy~\mathrm d x
\\[1ex] &= 14/9
\\[2ex]\mathsf {Var}(Y) &= \mathsf E(Y^2)-\mathsf E(Y)^2
\\[1ex] &= 26/81
\\[2ex]\mathsf E(XY) &= \int_0^1\int_0^2 xy f(x,y)~\mathrm dy~\mathrm d x
\\[1ex] &= 43/54
\\[2ex]\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y) &= \mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y)
\\[1ex] &= -1/162
\\[2ex]\mathsf{Corr}(X,Y) &= (-1/162)/(\surd[(73/1620)(26/81)])
\\[1ex]&=-\surd(5/1898)
\\[1ex]&\approx -0.051325938368630364195576486370191526370379503588767652076654564...
\end{align}$